# for loop in algpseudocode

Tags: algorithmicx

I want change my pseudocode

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\makeatletter



\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{AIP}\label{AIPal}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State \textit{$\sum^{N_agent}_{i=1}$$L_A$} $\gets$ position of \textit{$agent_i$}
\State \emph{loop}:
\State \textit{$i$}$\gets$ 1         
\State \textit{$i$ plus 1}
\If {\textit{distance(eNB,$Agent_i$)} $< \delta$} \textit{close $agent_i$}
\If {\textit{distance(eNB,$Agent_i$)}$>\Delta$} \textit{$agent_i$ power equals $\alpha$} 
\State \textbf{goto} loop
\EndIf                                 
\EndIf                                 
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

to for loop but I don't know how to transform it  to \For code. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option: use of `algorithm2e` and `algorithm` environment.

```
\usepackage[linesnumbered,boxed]{algorithm2e}         % first image
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}  % second image
```

[image]

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,boxed]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
%\SetAlgoNoLine              %To remove vertical line, activate this \SetAlgoNoLine 
\caption{AIP}\label{AIPal}
%\begin{algorithmic}[1]
 \textit{$\sum^{N_{agent}}_{i=1}$$L_A$} $\gets$ position of \textit{$agent_i$}

Set \textit{$i$}=1 

\While{\textit{$i$} $ < {N_{agent}}$}{
\textit{$i$}= \textit{$i$} + 1

%\State \textit{$i$ plus 1}
\If {\textit{distance(eNB,$Agent_i$)} $< \delta$}{ 
\textit{close $agent_i$}
}
\If {\textit{distance(eNB,$Agent_i$)}$>\Delta$} {\textit{$agent_i$ power equals $\alpha$} 
}%\EndIf                                 
}%\EndIf                              
%\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure whether this is what you're after exactly...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{AIP}\label{AIPal}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State $\displaystyle \sum^{N_{\text{agent}}}_{i = 1} L_A \gets \text{position of agent}_i$
    \State $i \gets 1$
    \State \emph{loop}:
      \State $i \gets i + 1$
      \If {$\text{distance}(\text{eNB},\text{agent}_i) < \delta$}
        \State close $\text{agent}_i$
        \If {$\text{distance}(\text{eNB},\text{agent}_i) > \Delta$}
          \State $\text{agent}_i$ power equals $\alpha$
          \State \textbf{goto} \emph{loop}
        \EndIf
      \EndIf
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Since the `algorithmic` environment with a `[1]` optional argument provides numbered lines. Use those as your looping identifiers:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{AIP}\label{AIPal}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State $\displaystyle \sum^{N_{\text{agent}}}_{i = 1} L_A \gets \text{position of agent}_i$
    \State $i \gets 1$
    \State $i \gets i + 1$ \label{loop}
    \If {$\text{distance}(\text{eNB},\text{agent}_i) < \delta$}
      \State close $\text{agent}_i$
      \If {$\text{distance}(\text{eNB},\text{agent}_i) > \Delta$}
        \State $\text{agent}_i$ power equals $\alpha$
        \State \textbf{goto} \ref{loop}
      \EndIf
    \EndIf
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```